# How to Map dates by their week in Java?

Tags: java

I had a list of objects and want to map them by their week numbers.

I've looked at using something like

```
private static int getWeekOfYear(LocalDate date) {
    WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault());
    return date.get(wf.weekOfYear());
}
```

The issue is that I don't want to do this by the week number in a year.

I want to have a `Map<Integer, List<DTO>>` where the `Integers` will be 1, 2, 3, ...

I had sorted the original `List<DTO>` by date and then I can get the first `DTO.getDate()` to determine when week 1 begins.

My problem is then iterating over the `DTO's` and determining which week number each one will be in. I feel like I'll have to find the day of the week, then work out how many days until the start of the next week e.g. if the first date is Wednesday, then week 2 will start in 5 days and then each subsequent week will be a further 7 days.

I'm really struggling to find a nice way of writing this. So am wondering if anyone can think of a good way of creating this `Map`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WeekField` has a overloaded method to specify the start day of the week and number of days in first week.

Since the DTO `List` is already sorted and the first day of week would be the starting day and 7 days from that day would be the next week.

```
    List<DTO> dtos = ...//  sorted
    LocalDate firstDate = dtos.get(0).getDate();
    WeekFields weekFields = WeekFields.of(firstDate.getDayOfWeek(), 7);  // to override the default start day and no of days in first week
    Map<Integer, List<DTO>> map = dtos.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(dto -> dto.getDate().get(weekFields.weekOfYear())));
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically you want to look into the new Java8 [date/time](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_datetime_api.htm) APIs when doing such computations on date.

And then please note: are you sure you want to use a *Map* here?
If I get your input right, you say that the keys will run 1, 2, 3, ... anyway? So - when you know that the keys will just be a sequence of numbers, why not use a list then?

Another alternative would be to use a TreeSet and a **custom** compartor. If you use the comparator to **sort** your DTO objects based on their date, the TreeSet will automatically put them into the correct order!

Answer (score 1):

Try JodaTime's week of year format: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/field.html#weekyear

> A week based year is one where dates are expressed as a day of week,
>   week number and year (week based). The following description is of the
>   ISO8601 standard used by implementations of this method in this
>   library. Weeks run from 1 to 52-53 in a week based year. The first day
>   of the week is defined as Monday and given the value 1. The first week
>   of a year is defined as the first week that has at least four days in
>   the year. As a result of this definition, week 1 may extend into the
>   previous year, and week 52/53 may extend into the following year.
>   Hence the need for the year of weekyear field. For example, 2003-01-01
>   was a Wednesday. This means that five days, Wednesday to Sunday, of
>   that week are in 2003. Thus the whole week is considered to be the
>   first week of 2003. Since all weeks start on Monday, the first week of
>   2003 started on 2002-12-30, ie. in 2002. The week based year has a
>   specific text format.

```
2002-12-30 (Monday 30th December 2002) would be represented as 2003-W01-1
2003-01-01 (Wednesday 1st January 2003) would be represented as 2003-W01-3.
```

Comment: Why joda? Isn't all joda in Java8 by now? What I mean is: why do you suggest a "third party external" library, if java8 has the same features built-in?

Comment: I've failed to see that the question was for Java8 and later. It's certainly relevant for previous versions of Java.

Comment: Makes sense. And for the record: downvoter not me that was.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do, is find the first day of the week of the first date, and create the map using this date as reference :

```
private static Map<Long, List<DTO>> mapByWeek(final List<DTO> dtos) {
    if (dtos.isEmpty())
        return Collections.emptyMap();

    // find the first day of first week
    final LocalDate referenceDate = dtos.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(DTO::getDate)).findFirst()
            .map(dto -> dto.getDate().with(WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault()).dayOfWeek(), 1)).get();

    // group by number of weeks of difference with the reference date
    return dtos.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(dto -> ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between(referenceDate, dto.getDate()) + 1));
}
```